# Nav-index property in css

Tags: css

How nav-index property is used?

if the nav-index property of textbox1 is  set to 10,that of text box2 to 5 and that text box3 to 8,what will the navigation order?

Answer (score 1):

The nav-index property is currently supported only in Opera.

Definition and Usage : The nav-index property specifies the sequential navigation order ("tabbing order") for an

Default value:  auto

auto :  The element's tabbing order is assigned by the browser
number :    Indicates the tabbing order for the element. 1 means first
inherit :   Specifies that the value of the nav-index property should be inherited from the parent element

[Try This](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_nav) in Opera to figure it out